# Crear en la misma vista (con iframe) un PDF en Codeigniter 3 con FPDF

Tags: php, codeigniter

Soy nuevo con *Codeigniter* y necesito generar un *PDF* con esta librería que uso frecuentemente, tengo duda en la generación que envío por *AJAX*:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo site_url('lecturas_pdf/')?>",
    type:"POST",  
    //dataType:"JSON",
    success:function(data){  
        alert(data);
        $('#lectura_pdf').src = data;
        //alert(data[0]);
        console.log(data);
        window.open(
            'data:application/pdf,'+encodeURIComponent(data),
            'Batch Print',
            'width=600,height=600,location=_newtab'
        );
    }
});
```

Este es mi controlador:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
* 
*/
class Lecturas extends Castor_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('lectura');
    }
    public function index(){
        //$this->load->view('lecturas/lecturas');
        $this->load->model('barrio');
        $data['barrio']=$this->barrio->findAll();
        $data['view']='lecturas/lecturas';
        $data['output']='';
        $this->load->view('layouts_backend_lte_datatables/main', $data);        
    }
    public function listar_clientes(){
        $barrio_id = $this->input->post('barrio_id');
        $mes_consumo = $this->input->post('mes_consumo');
        $list = $this->lectura->medidor_barrio($barrio_id);

        foreach ($list as $medidor) {
            $consumo = $this->lectura->lectura_mes($medidor->id, $mes_consumo);
        }
    }
    public function listar_clientes_data(){
        $barrio_id = $this->input->post('barrio_id');
        $mes_consumo = $this->input->post('mes_consumo');

        $list = $this->lectura->get_mes_consumo($barrio_id, $mes_consumo);

        $no=0;
        $output =  '<div class="table-responsive">';  
        $output .= '<table class="table table-bordered">';  
        $output .= '<tr>';  
        $output .= '<th width="5%">Ord</th>'; 
        $output .= '<th width="36%">Nombre</th>';  
        $output .= '<th width="18%">Medidor</th>';  
        $output .= '<th width="18%">Lectura anterior</th>';  
        $output .= '<th width="18%">Lectura nueva</th>';  
        $output .= '<th width="50%">Est</th>';  
        $output .= '</tr>';

        foreach ($list as $data) {
            $no++;
            $output .= '<tr>';   
            $output .= '<td>'.$no.'</td>';   
            $output .= '<td>'.$data->apellido.'</td>';   
            $output .= '<td>'.$data->codigo.'</td>';   
            $output .= '<td class="data" data-id2="'.$data->id.'" contenteditable></td>';  
            $output .= '<td class="lectura_actual" data-id3="'.$data->id.'" contenteditable></td>';  
            //$output .= '<td class="lectura_anterior" data-id2="'.$data->id.'" contenteditable>'.$data->lectura_anterior.'</td>';  
            //$output .= '<td class="lectura_actual" data-id3="'.$data->id.'" contenteditable>'.$data->lectura_actual.'</td>';  
            $output .= '<td></td>';   
            $output .= '</tr>'; 
        }
        $output .= '</table></div>';  

        echo $output;
    }
}
?>
```

Esta es la salida:

```
%PDF-1.3
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/Resources 2 0 R
/Contents 4 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 558>>
stream
x�m�Kr�0��>����"��g��IS�l�8��U�Ngz�Ғ(�7Ґ>�!��Ì�T�w6/���H���,�[Lh��(��tW}T��jΟ�|�ݮ�:
�����5pU*�
Nͥ�e}4A���f�& C�@�W��[|����Bb��%c�9���خ%ᗑ��!�7؂�%9J�N�ȶ�o?�})�}�pA���9�ed�R����$"8dt���:o����׻� 6�Oզ�\��c*Nc�GF1U�HZ���?/���4J����Qd&��1!��tJ��Q�$n\�E��҄S�Smaa�6S��PJ��,�������M}>`m�j�~h=�[R�<�nc�`2�v��� �d�=�h���u�"�¾�3,.M��v�ΝG�C� �t03.�0�'�K�Z-�tC�}�"P�6�t�C����@��6{{�V�Q���WXkۼ'�{T�,�V����
_zd�^���Ëq��ן�t�G��=�i�0����T�.Ծ9j߅;�ڛ�ŗO�e:.w7���d�Л�;�(f��
endstream
endobj
1 0 obj
<</Type /Pages
/Kids [3 0 R ]
/Count 1
/MediaBox [0 0 595.28 841.89]
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 364>>
stream
x�]R�n�0��>��L�%�DI�8���~�%E*r�ﻻvҪHX�gvVk?/���Ῑ��`]�[�x5
�3\z��P�}����PO���j�Jݍ^���x6/f�����������|���4}�z�����}���@�,ۖ-��˺E�u�^�,���<�
�Z_�K� IQ����Yd����C�K�_�%q�8>�!J"V!2&bGģ%r"H��D��\}2EL1n��h�j���e��"a*H����:��d��9c���[�X1~��"�3�g��Ñ�;O��<r_�)-�<%a�I9��8v�s�4z0�97Wcp���x�4�^���M�D*�
��
endstream
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Type /Font
/BaseFont /Helvetica-Bold
/Subtype /Type1
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
/ToUnicode 5 0 R
>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<</Type /Font
/BaseFont /Helvetica-Oblique
/Subtype /Type1
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
/ToUnicode 5 0 R
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
/Font <<
/F1 6 0 R
/F2 7 0 R
>>
/XObject <<
>>
>>
endobj
8 0 obj
<<
/Title (Lista de clientes)
/Producer (FPDF 1.81)
/CreationDate (D:20170315145048)
>>
endobj
9 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 1 0 R
>>
endobj
xref
0 10
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000715 00000 n 
0000001475 00000 n 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000000087 00000 n 
0000000802 00000 n 
0000001236 00000 n 
0000001354 00000 n 
0000001589 00000 n 
0000001692 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/Size 10
/Root 9 0 R
/Info 8 0 R
>>
startxref
1741
%%EOF
Lectura.pdf
```

Comment: Que es lo quieres lograr?? Necesitas mostrar el pdf en un iframe? y que es lo que tienes en la url lecturas_pdf??

Comment: Quiero generar el PDF en la misma vista ya sea con iframe u otro objeto. No quiero que el PDF se abra en otra ventana o se descargue.